# Filter gridview according to user and its role - in .net 4 web appication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, user-management

I am developing a web site where I show grid view with customers in the left side.
currently I show all the customers from the DB. The user can click on a customer to show his details.

The customers and customers details is taking from SQL DB has the tables Customers and table of customersData.

I Manage Web Site Users with Roles using the built in functionality of microsoft. I created users with role administrator and user with role manager.

I want that the manager will see only his customers and not other manager's customers.

I guess that for that I need to associate customers to ManagerID. **but how do I do it ? The users with the roles are not in my DB, but in microsoft. Customers is my table, but ManagerID have have to take from microsoft DB**. There must be a way.

Appreciate any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "UserId" from the "aspnet_Users" table based on "UserName".  I would suggest you add a field to your customers table to hold the ID.  Then you can query the customers for the ID of the logged on user.